# Trace/BPT trap when running feedparser inside a Thread object

Tags: python, multithreading, feedparser

I am trying to run a Thread to parse a list of links using the universal feed parser, but when I start the thread I get a Trace/BPT trap.

Here's the code I am using:

```
class parseRssFiles(Thread):
   def __init__ (self,rssLinks):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      self.rssLinks = rssLinks
   def run(self):
      self.rssContents = [ feedparser.parse(link) for link in rssLinks]
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Link to the report generated by Mac OS X 10.6.2: http://simaom.com/trace.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a working test case, it is hard to know for sure but I suspect you are running into the problem documented in [Python tracker issue 7144](http://bugs.python.org/issue7144), namely, trying to initialize the `CoreFoundation` framework on other than the main thread.  That problem is fixed in Python 2.6.5 which you could install from python.org or MacPorts.  An untested workaround for the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.1 in 10.6 may be to execute something innocuous in the main thread that will cause `CoreFoundation` to be initialized before starting any secondary threads. Something like this in the main thread might do it:

```
import locale
locale.getdefautlocale()
```